# how to use notification in qt-android and android version is 8.0

Tags: android, qt, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I know that how to use notification when android's version is 7.0  ,but I I do not know know when android version is surpass 8.0

Comment: Please describe your issue when you implement the push notification in qt-android and android version is 8.0

Comment: what kind of notification are you having issues with? if you're dealing with push notifications then qt does not have, AFAIK, a native method (except for 3rd party framework Felgo https://felgo.com/). so you should show some code of what you're trying to implement. If you are using the local notification then you might have a look to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html

Comment: thx every one ，I have solved this problem

Comment: on this：https://juejin.im/post/5ce79be45188255be425e270